# Notation Issue related to inverse function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, index-notation

So I was asked a few days ago this question: Consider $(x,y)=(f(u,v),g(u,v))$ with $\partial(x,y)/\partial(u,v)\neq0$, show that $$\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}\right)_v\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)_y=\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}\right)_u\left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)_x$$
and the thing is, I'm actually confused about the notation. I tried with small examples assuming that the subindex means partial derivative... but it doesn't seem to work, neither I've fund useful stuff online. Any hint would very appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: The subscript tells you what is being held constant.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to find something about it after all. Now, is it necessary to indicate such subscript in this context, given that $x$ only depends on u and v? so I see it there is no confusion in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small trick involved. Since, $\partial(x,y)/\partial(u,v) \neq 0$, we can assume a non-zero $|\mathbf J|$ for the transformation.
$$
\mathbf J = \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \begin{bmatrix}
\partial x/\partial u & \partial x/\partial v\\
\partial y/\partial u & \partial y/\partial v
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It is simple to find the inverse of this matrix
\begin{align}
\mathbf{J}^{-1} = \frac{1}{|\mathbf J|} \begin{bmatrix}
\partial y/\partial v & -\partial x/\partial v\\
-\partial y/\partial u & \partial x/\partial u
\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}
\end{align}
But the following equation also holds by nature of inverse transformation
\begin{align}
\mathbf J^{-1} = \frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} = \begin{bmatrix}
\partial u/\partial x & \partial u/\partial y\\
\partial v/\partial x & \partial v/\partial y
\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}
\end{align}

You can prove your result using the equation (1)$=$(2).

Comment: Cool, thank you!